# How to execute GRASS module directly on a geodata file in the command line?

Tags: grass-gis

I have a geopackage of lines that I want to run `v.clean` on. I have GRASS 7.8 installed:

```
me@server:~/grass_proc$ grass78 -v
GRASS GIS 7.8.2

Geographic Resources Analysis Support System (GRASS) is Copyright,
1999-2019 by the GRASS Development Team, and licensed under terms of the
GNU General Public License (GPL) version >=2.

This GRASS GIS 7.8.2 release is coordinated and produced by
the GRASS Development Team with contributions from all over the world.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
General Public License for more details.
```

I am working on a remove server via SSH. I can figure out how to do interactively, by following these steps:

1. Run `grass78`
2. Create a workspace
3. Close the GUI (which somehow is able to be used via SSH)
4. Run these commands, in this order:

.

```
v.import input=network_to_clean.gpkg output=network_to_clean
v.clean input=network_to_clean output=cleaned_network tool=break
v.out.ogr input=cleaned_network output=cleaned_network.gpkg format=GPKG
```

It works fine. But I would like to do this all automatically, without having to create a workspace beforehand, literally just run a single script which only takes `network_to_clean.gpkg`. It could be a shell script, I don't really care. But how can I do this without having to use the GUI to set the workspace? And can it be cleaned up automatically (i.e. delete the workspace afterwards)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THis is certainly possible, and built into GRASS by taking advantage of an envivironment variable `GRASS_BATCH_JOB`. The procedure is explained quite well in the [GRASS Wiki](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_and_Shell#GRASS_Batch_jobs).

In short, you create a temporary GRASS Location, choosing the coordinate reference system from the existing geopackage file for reference. Then you define the `GRASS_BATCH_JOB` environ variable, pointing it to the script to be run. Then start GRASS in that temp Location. The script will run, doing whatever commands you entered into the batch script, then GRASS exists. And finally just remove that environ variable (and the temp location).

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I needed, thank you!

Comment: Also do-able w/o environment variable and with more explicit calls: `grass -e -c EPSG:3413 G` and then `grass ./G/PERMANENT --exec script.sh`.